# Inconsistent results when nesting multiple LinearLayouts

Tags: android, android-layout

The problem is that on different screen sizes the 2 ImageViews in the code below are located at slightly different positions. I have no idea what's wrong, theoretically everything should be displayed identically on all screens, becouse i'm using layout_weights...

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/menu_play_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg_color" >

    <!-- relative layout contains 2 nested LinearLayouts here -->
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/game_result_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <!-- First LinearLayout -->
       <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:weightSum="600">

       <View android:layout_weight="99" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp"/>

       <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="75"
        android:contentDescription="@string/star_desc"
        android:src="@drawable/victory"/>

       <View android:layout_weight="257" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp"/>

           <!-- Second LinearLayout -->
           <LinearLayout
           android:orientation="horizontal"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:weightSum="1024">

          <View android:layout_weight="538" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

           <ImageView
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="45"
           android:contentDescription="@string/star_desc"
           android:src="@drawable/star"/>

           </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

However, the problem arises only after adding the second nested LinearLayout. With only the first LinearLayout, the ImageView there is displayed on the right position on all screens. After nesting the second LinearLayout like above, both ImageViews change their positions slightly on different screens.

update:
The solution provided by Ben75 fixed the vertical inconsistencies but some minor horizontal differences still remain.
This is the updated second (nested) LinearLayout code:

```
...
<LinearLayout
           android:orientation="horizontal"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="40"
           android:weightSum="1024">
...
```

Here is a good looking UI on one emulator:
[image]

And here are horizontal inconsistencies on an emulator with smaller screen:

[image]

Note: In my second layout in the code above I'm trying to set the golden star's position to cover the gray star in the background image. In first case it works but in second as you can see, the star doesn't completely fit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In secong LinearLayout you have :

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

but since it is a child view of the first LinearLayout (which is using weight) : it must also use weight and you must set it's `android:layout_height="0dp"`

---

After looking at screenshot, it seems that yellow star is a little to small (in height) and I guess this is because of the `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` so try to set the layout height to match parent :

```
<ImageView
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_weight="45"
       android:contentDescription="@string/star_desc"
       android:src="@drawable/star"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Indeed, I've done as you suggested and it fixed but only vertical inconsistencies. Horizontal differences still remain. Do you see any more problems in my code?

Comment: The differences aren't huge but noticable especially becosue I'm trying to cover 1 image with another of the same size... Could it be android bug cause I really can't see what could possibly be wrong

Comment: put a screenshot of what you have now may help.

Comment: uff, that was a really annoying bug to detect... The problem was with my graphics. The 3 gray stars and the whole dialog box were 1 image and the yellow star appeared to be smaller becouse gray stars were scaled all together with the dialog box as 1 image. The yellow star was scaled independently. That probably caused some inconsistencies in their sizes...